# Can't delete entry from Access database from C# even that the sql command is solid

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, sql-delete

When I use the delete command it says it deletes it but in the database file the line is still there

```
public void UserDelete(int user_id)
{
   cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Kids WHERE user_id="+user_id+"";
   MessageBox.Show("נמחק משתמש : " + user_id + "\n" + UserGetField(user_id,1)+" "+ UserGetField(user_id,2), "מחיקת משתמש");
   con.Open(); // open the connection
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```

Ok, solved it... removed the `UserGetField...` had to be "smart" and say what I deleted

```
public void UserDelete(int user_id)
{
   cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Kids WHERE user_id="+user_id+"";
   MessageBox.Show("נמחק משתמש : " + user_id, "מחיקת משתמש");
   con.Open(); // open the connection
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```

Comment: How are you verifying that the row is still present in the table?

Comment: You should use parameters instead of concatenation to build your SQL. Look at the [DbCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.parameters.aspx) collection, and find the right type depending on what `cmd` and `con` is here.

Comment: When you copy the sql code to the Access query design window, does the record delete?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i check by the user_id i get. in the table Kids where user_id = user_id it should delete it

Comment: @Remou how do i do that?

Comment: Is the `user_id` referenced in another table where the column is defined as a foreign key column on the `Kids` table?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the other command like add new or update works, just delete doesn't work now for some reason (worked before)

Comment: @Oded `user_id` is the index in the `Kids` table

Comment: have u tried adding `cmd.connection=con;` and see if it works..??

Comment: I figured as much. Not what I am asking. Is there another table (say, `Parents_To_Kids`), which has a column that references the `user_id` column of the `Kids` table and is defined as a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) constraint? If you don't know what a foreign key is, please read that link first.

Comment: @RamandeepSingh its part of the constractor  `string DBpath = "c:\\Library.mdb";
        public DataBase()
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = "+DBpath);
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
        }`

Comment: @Oded no, there are 2 tables, `Kids` and `Item` no foreign key, there is 0 connection between them

Comment: Solved it... look at main post

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct? If my memory helps me the right syntax in JET SQL is DELETE * FROM xxxx ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cmd.Connection.Open()` before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`